I am having errors in sqlalchemy with relationships such as many to many and one to many etc
I am new to sqlalchemy and I have defined a schema using orm for a chat application, but I am having issues with the schema's relationships, this is what the models are right now, I want some help in how these would be done properly
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.rooms - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

"""
Models
"""
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey, Unicode, Table
from flask import Flask
# from core.config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///memory"

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

db = SQLAlchemy(app, model_class=Base)


def generate_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())


users_in_room = Table("users_in_room",
                      Base.metadata,
                      Column("user_id", String, ForeignKey("user.userID")),
                      Column("room_id", String, ForeignKey("room.room_id")))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    """
    USER MODEL
    """
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column("userID", String, primary_key=True, default=generate_uuid)
    username = db.Column("user_name", String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column("password", String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column("email", String, nullable=False)
    created_rooms = db.relationship("Room", backref="created_by")
    rooms = db.relationship("Room", backref="users_in_rooms") # One To Many
    messages = db.relationship("Message", backref="sent_by_user")

   
    def set_password(self, secret):
        """
        set password method, sets the password by converting it in to a hash
        and then stores that hash in the database
        """
        # password hash
        return generate_password_hash(secret)
   
    def check_password(self, secret):
        """
        check password method, checks the password validity by comparing the entered password
        during login, with stored hash of the loaded column's password field, the column is
        loaded in the login view function, using db.session.scalar(...)
        """
        return check_password_hash(self.password, secret)


    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = self.set_password(password)
        self.email = email


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User : {self.username}'


class Room(db.Model):
    """
    ROOM MODEL
    """
    __tablename__ = "room"
    room_name = db.Column("room_name", String, nullable=False)
    room_id = db.Column("room_id", primary_key=True, default=generate_uuid)
    room_banner = db.Column("room_banner", String, nullable=True)
    created_by = db.relationship("User", ForeignKey("created_by.id"))
    joining_url = db.Column("joining_url", String, nullable=False)
    messages: Mapped[list["Message"]] = relationship(backref="sent_to_room")
    users = db.relationship("User", backref="users_in_room") # Many To One


    def __init__(self, room_name: String, room_banner: String,
                joining_url: String, created_by: User):
        self.room_name = room_name
        self.room_banner = room_banner
        self.joining_url = joining_url
        self.created_by = created_by


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.joining_url


class Message(db.Model):
    """
    MESSAGE MODEL
    """
    __tablename__ = "message"
    message_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))
    room_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("room.room_id"))
    message_body = db.Column("message_body", String)
    # message_body can contain image, gif or sound clip, video, stickers -> BLOB (binary large object)
    room_id = db.relationship("Room", ForeignKey("users_in_room.id")) # Many To One
    sent_by = db.relationship("user", ForeignKey("sent_by_user.id"))
    date = db.Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)


    def __init__(self, message_body: String, sent_by: User, sent_to_room: Room):
        self.message_body = message_body
        self.sent_to_room = sent_to_room
        self.sent_by = sent_by


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.message_body




ForeignKey fields should be Columns, not relationships, with a data type that matches the id field that they reference.  See the docs.

I have went through the docs, now I have tried everything, but I get error with creator_id column  creator_id = db.mapped_column(String, ForeignKey("user.userID")) # Many To One I need to get clarification on the relationship structure of these, although I am conceptually clear, but I want to know the right way to implement these in the orm
